# Nestjs doesnt get changes of data from database till i restart the application

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

i have a problem with my nestjs application i dnt see the changes in the data i inserted in my database till i restart the application everytime

```
const connectionId = this.getCustomConnectionName(tenant);
try {
  getConnection(connectionId);
  next();
} catch (error) {
  const createdConnection: Connection = await createConnection({
    name: connectionId,
    type: 'mysql',
    host: this.configService.get<string>('database.host'),
    port: this.configService.get<number>('database.port'),
    username: tenant.dbLogin,
    password: tenant.dbPassword,
    database: tenant.dbName,
    insecureAuth: true,
    entities: [
      Tenant,
      User,
      UserView,
      Company,
      CompanyView,
      Invoice,
      InvoiceView,
      Item,
      ItemView,
      Invoicearchiv,
      InvoicearchivView,
      Itemarchiv,
      ItemarchivView,
      Dictionary,
    ],
    logging: this.configService.get<boolean>('database.logging')
  });
```

[okayy this is what i have inserted in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJuWx.png)

and this is what my GET request is giving me

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "invoiceno": "1456",
    "description": "xqsqsq",
    "taxrate": 2,
    "issuedate": "2021-10-04T23:00:00.000Z",
    "duedate": "2021-10-19T23:00:00.000Z",
    "note": "facc",
    "taxamount": 10,
    "subtotal": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "status": false,
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-18T23:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedBy": 1,
    "createdAt": "2021-10-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "items": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "invoiceno": "14568",
    "description": "xqsqsq",
    "taxrate": 2,
    "issuedate": "2021-10-04T23:00:00.000Z",
    "duedate": "2021-10-19T23:00:00.000Z",
    "note": "facc",
    "taxamount": 10,
    "subtotal": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "status": false,
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-18T23:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedBy": 1,
    "createdAt": "2021-10-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "items": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "invoiceno": "145684",
    "description": "xqsqsq",
    "taxrate": 2,
    "issuedate": "2021-10-04T23:00:00.000Z",
    "duedate": "2021-10-19T23:00:00.000Z",
    "note": "facc",
    "taxamount": 10,
    "subtotal": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "status": false,
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-18T23:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedBy": 1,
    "createdAt": "2021-10-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "items": []
},
{
    "id": 180,
    "invoiceno": "255",
    "description": "xqsqsq",
    "taxrate": 2,
    "issuedate": "2021-10-04T23:00:00.000Z",
    "duedate": "2021-10-19T23:00:00.000Z",
    "note": "facc",
    "taxamount": 10,
    "subtotal": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "status": false,
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-04T21:18:36.000Z",
    "updatedBy": 0,
    "createdAt": null,
    "createdBy": null,
    "items": []
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "invoiceno": "255",
    "description": "xqsqsq",
    "taxrate": 2,
    "issuedate": "2021-10-04T23:00:00.000Z",
    "duedate": "2021-10-19T23:00:00.000Z",
    "note": "facc",
    "taxamount": 10,
    "subtotal": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "status": false,
    "updatedAt": "2021-10-04T21:18:12.000Z",
    "updatedBy": 0,
    "createdAt": null,
    "createdBy": null,
    "items": []
}
```

]

and i already deleted those but its still showing them its like there is delay

and this is how my get function

```
public async findAll(connection: Connection): Promise<InvoiceRep[]> {

  const queryBuilder = await this.getQueryBuilderWithJoins(connection);

  return await queryBuilder.getMany();

  }
private async getQueryBuilderWithJoins(connection: Connection) {

const queryBuilder = await connection.getRepository(InvoiceView).createQueryBuilder('inv');

queryBuilder.leftJoinAndMapMany('inv.items', ItemView, 'i', 'inv.id = i.idInvoice');

queryBuilder.getQuery()

return queryBuilder;
   }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use the above? What's the context of this?

Comment: those are the entities i have in my application

Comment: i just wanna know what am i doing wrong for thid bug to occur

Comment: I don't know what the error is. What's suppose to be happening?

Comment: the problem is lets say i insert data in a table and if i do a get request to see whats in that table its empty until i restart the application and then i m able to see

Comment: It'd be useful to see what code you're running for these inserts and reads. It doesn't sound like something that should be happening

Comment: okay can you check now i edited to maybe help you see

Answer (score 0):

1. need to see full the usage example - is this your [How to query data into multiple tables in Nest.js using QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68549324/how-to-query-data-into-multiple-tables-in-nest-js-using-querybuilder)? e.g. `InvoiceView` is not clear?
2. Why you do not use a classic DB connection example in the Nest Docs?
3. What kind of DB do you use? The description above is similar to the old version of Realm under debug mode ;)
4. Do you restart DB each time as the Application too?